# Postgres slow query with order by, index and limit

Tags: postgresql, performance, order-by, postgresql-9.6, limits, query-performance

I am trying to improve the performance of a postgres(9.6) query. Here is my schema and table contains about 60 million rows.

```
          Column          |            Type             | Modifiers
--------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 transaction_id           | text                        | not null
 network_merchant_name    | text                        |
 network_merchant_id      | text                        |
 network_merchant_mcc     | integer                     |
 network_merchant_country | text                        |
 issuer_country           | text                        |
 merchant_id              | text                        |
 remapped_merchant_id     | text                        |
 created_at               | timestamp without time zone |
 updated_at               | timestamp without time zone |
 remapped_at              | timestamp without time zone |
Indexes:
    "mapped_transactions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (transaction_id)
    "ix_mapped_transactions_remapped_at" btree (remapped_at NULLS FIRST)
```

Here is the query I am trying to execute.

```
SELECT *
FROM mapped_transactions
ORDER BY remapped_at ASC NULLS FIRST
LIMIT 10000;
```

Here is the query plan:

```
    QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.57..1511.67 rows=10000 width=146) (actual time=327049.374..327345.341 rows=10000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=574937 read=210425 dirtied=356 written=4457
   I/O Timings: read=146625.381 write=59.637
   ->  Index Scan using ix_mapped_transactions_remapped_at on mapped_transactions  (cost=0.57..16190862.91 rows=107145960 width=146) (actual time=327049.364..327339.402 rows=10000 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=574937 read=210425 dirtied=356 written=4457
         I/O Timings: read=146625.381 write=59.637
 Planning time: 0.125 ms
 Execution time: 327348.322 ms
(8 rows)
```

I don't understand why it takes so much time when there is an index on the `remapped_at`column.

On the other hand if I order in reverse it is fast.

```
SELECT *
FROM mapped_transactions
ORDER BY remapped_at DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 10000;
```

and the plan is:

```
QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.57..1511.67 rows=10000 width=146) (actual time=0.020..9.268 rows=10000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1802
   ->  Index Scan Backward using ix_mapped_transactions_remapped_at on mapped_transactions  (cost=0.57..16190848.04 rows=107145866 width=146) (actual time=0.018..4.759 rows=10000 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=1802
 Planning time: 0.080 ms
 Execution time: 11.561 ms
(6 rows)
```

Can someone please help me how I can improve the performance of the first query?

## Updates

1. I solved this by rebuilding the table and reindexing the data. `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` was not an option because the table was being used and I did not want to lock it.
2. The performance of the index is deteriorating very fast. I rebuilt the index 7 hours ago and the performance was good. Now the queries answer in about 10s. Please note that that this table is write heavy. How can I make the index fast? Do I have to re-index the table frequently? There are no deletions in this table but a lot of updates.

Comment: Hmmm... this is a very interesting question which has me stumped! I'm giving it a +1 for putting in table definitions and plans (unusual for a first post!). How many rows in your table? How many remapped_at are `NULL`? 9ms to > 4 mins - wow!

Comment: Like I have mentioned in the post there are 60 million rows in the table. There should not be any NULL in remapped_at but it is possible to insert NULL for legacy purposes. At the time when i ran the query there were 0 NULL in tat column.

Comment: Ooops (re. 60M :-) )! There are some very knowledgeable PostgreSQL guys around here - but it is Sat. evening/afternoon! Try editing your question on Monday at 13:00 UTC, better responses then! - it'll go back into the active questions list! Let me know via a comment (put `@Vérace` in the body). I'll bring it to the chat room - I think it's worth pursuing!

Comment: Can you run the query with `explain (analyze, buffers)` and edit the output in the question?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I have updated the post with `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Comment: I wonder if this behavior is consistent (e.g. if you get the similar timing if you execute queries in different order multiple times with autovacuum off). `dirtied=356 written=4457` part implies the first query checks and sets "visibility" bit which is quite expensive operation

Comment: @a1ex07 I am not familiar with "visibility" bit. But to answer your question, yes this behaviour is consistent. Although I believe autovacuum is on. I get similar times when I run similar queries. Slow when scanning the index in ASC order and fast when scanning the index in DESC order.

Comment: @Zeeshan I would be curious if my test case below fails for you. If It works, I would be interested in seeing if a `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` fixed the problem.

Comment: @Zeeshan :  You may want to check http://www.cybertec.at/speeding-up-things-with-hint-bits/  , I have a feeling (not sure though) it's related to your case.

Comment: i'm voting to close, because there isn't enough information to recreate the problem. (unless my test case below fails for you in which case it's a 9.6-9.5 regression)

Comment: @EvanCarrollQWERHJKL the test case posted worked for me. `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` is not possible as this will lock the table and it is being used by other processes (reads and writes). I might be able to make a copy of it and run some more tests.

Comment: @Zeeshan sounds like a plan, `CREATE TABLE x ( LIKE mapped_transactions INCLUDING ALL ); INSERT INTO x TABLE mapped_transactions;` A vacuum full analyze on 40 million rows shouldn't take but a few minutes.

Comment: I did notice that your first query returns 8 rows, but your reverse sort query only returns 6 rows. I think it might have to do with some obscure data in cache. Or a faulty query plan. Or maybe just a broken index (Try rebuilding).

Comment: @EvanCarrollQWERHJKL So I rebuilt the table (Vacuum full analyze did not work because it was taking too long. I tried for 10 mins and then killed it). Now the queries are giving me proper response times. I guess the table or the index was broken originally. I did notice that the original table consumed about 30 GB of data when I checked postgres table size. The new table (with exact same data) consumes about 18 GB of data. I done have any explanation why the table was bigger. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Zeeshan: please add that as an answer and accept that answer so that your question is marked as resolved.

Comment: @EvanCarrollQWERHJKL The problem is happening again. See update 2 in post. The performance of the index is degrading over time. The table is write and update heavy and there are no deletions so it will grow over time. Do I have to frequently re-index or go with some other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran some more tests and it seems like this solution is not going to work for me. The index is constantly being degraded over time and if I don't re-index (or drop and create again) the queries I want to run will get slower and slower. There are ways to create the index without blocking other reads/writes but at this time I am not going to go with them because they are not easily scalable. I cannot solve this problem with the knowledge I have so I am going to go with another approach. This approach uses an index with a column that is constant and it never gets updated. Thanks everyone for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm with PostgreSQL 9.5. So this may be a regression. Sample data,

```
CREATE TABLE mapped_transactions(remapped_at)
AS
  SELECT CASE WHEN x::int % 42 = 0 THEN null ELSE x::int END
  FROM generate_series( 1, 40e6 )
    AS gs(x);

CREATE INDEX ON mapped_transactions (remapped_at NULLS FIRST);
VACUUM ANALYZE mapped_transactions;
```

Here we do `NULLS FIRST` and it works,

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM mapped_transactions
ORDER BY remapped_at ASC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 10000;
                                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.56..260.24 rows=10000 width=4) (actual time=0.069..4.308 rows=10000 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using mapped_transactions_remapped_at_idx on mapped_transactions  (cost=0.56..1038716.81 rows=40000016 width=4) (actual time=0.067..2.740 rows=10000 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.232 ms
 Execution time: 5.017 ms
(5 rows)
```

Trying `DESC NULLS LAST`

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM mapped_transactions
ORDER BY remapped_at DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 10000;
                                                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.56..260.24 rows=10000 width=4) (actual time=0.073..4.429 rows=10000 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan Backward using mapped_transactions_remapped_at_idx on mapped_transactions  (cost=0.56..1038716.81 rows=40000016 width=4) (actual time=0.071..2.865 rows=10000 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.114 ms
 Execution time: 5.137 ms
(5 rows)
```

You may have to work up a test case. It's not evident what you're experiencing.

Comment: this test case worked for me and I get the similar response time as you posted. I am still not sure what is wrong with my original table.